# Typed characters disappear when moving mouse (Firefox/Rikaichan/IBus-Mozc)

Tags: firefox, ibus, japanese, mozc

Characters sometimes disappears on Firefox:

1. Enable IBus-Mozc to type in Japanese
2. Type `g`
3. Type `a`. The character `が` appears. Don't type `Enter`.
4. Move the mouse
5. The character disappears

I would report a bug, but I have no idea who is at fault here:

- It only happens when Rikaichan (or Rikaisama) is activated
- It only happens on Firefox, not Chromium
- It only happens with IBus-Mozc (I have used other IMEs much though)
- It only happens on some text areas, not all. Facebook's chat box has the problem, as seen below

[image: screencast]

During this screencast I only typed `g` `a` `Enter` and moved the mouse. I never used `Backspace` nor `Delete` nor clicked anything.

**QUESTION: How can I find out what component is at fault here?**
Also, if there is a way to avoid the problem, I would be interested.

Output of `lsb_release -sd`:

```
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
```

Output of `ibus version`:

```
IBus 1.5.11
```

Output of `ibus read-config`:

```
SCHEMA: org.freedesktop.ibus.general
  dconf-preserve-name-prefixes: ['/desktop/ibus/engine/pinyin', '/desktop/ibus/engine/bopomofo', '/desktop/ibus/engine/hangul']
  use-system-keyboard-layout: true
  embed-preedit-text: true
  enable-by-default: false
  use-global-engine: true
  use-xmodmap: true
  switcher-delay-time: 400
  version: '1.5.11'
  engines-order: @as []
  preload-engines: ['xkb:us::eng']
  xkb-latin-layouts: ['ara', 'bg', 'cz', 'dev', 'gr', 'gur', 'in', 'jp(kana)', 'mal', 'mkd', 'ru', 'ua']
SCHEMA: org.freedesktop.ibus.general.hotkey
  next-engine: ['Alt+Shift_L']
  disable-unconditional: @as []
  enable-unconditional: @as []
  trigger: ['Control+space', 'Zenkaku_Hankaku', 'Alt+Kanji', 'Alt+grave', 'Hangul', 'Alt+Release+Alt_R']
  previous-engine: @as []
  prev-engine: @as []
  next-engine-in-menu: ['Alt+Shift_L']
  triggers: ['<Super>space']
SCHEMA: org.freedesktop.ibus.panel
  x: -1
  property-icon-delay-time: 500
  y: -1
  lookup-table-orientation: 1
  show: 0
  xkb-icon-rgba: '#415099'
  auto-hide-timeout: 10000
  show-im-name: false
  follow-input-cursor-when-always-shown: false
  custom-font: 'Sans 10'
  show-icon-on-systray: true
  use-custom-font: false
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `lsb_release -sd; ibus version; ibus read-config`

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer for the question but a work around for the problem.*

If you have no problem to switch input method into fcitx

```
sudo apt install fcitx-mozc
```

Then it works almost the same as ibus-mozc and it has fewer/less problems compare to ibus-mozc

Comment: Does it fix this particular problem?

Comment: I had the same problems you had and migrated ibus to fcitx until now, I don't see any problems above. It saved my time a lot.